# Convert IIS rules to Apache/HTACCESS Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis

How does one convert IIS Rewrite rules to Apache/htaccess rewrite rules?

Specifically, I'm looking to convert this IIS rule to Apache:

```
<rule name="SEO">
     <match url="^([^/]+/)*([^/]+)\.(\d+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?id={R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here it is:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+/)*([^/]+)\.(\d+)$ index.php?id=$3
```